# asterisk mute all channels on a confbridge by single command

Tags: node.js, open-source, asterisk, asteriskami, asterisk-ari

I am working on a solution with asterisk, that needs to enter all caller channels in a confbridge and then there is admin user that can mute and unmute any channel at runtime by it's choice.

**All of this is working.**

**But now I am stuck at a scenario** where admin has to unmute multiple caller channels, and to mute all of them I have to go through a loop and run the mute command for all channels. I need to avoid this, So, Is there any **asterisk confbridge command that can mute all channels in that specific confbridge at once** ?

I need a asterisk command or AMI action or anything from ARI that can do it ?  Or is there any other way around for it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you not found how to do that, it is described everywhere

```
pro-sip*CLI> confbridge <TAB pressed here>
kick    list    lock    mute    record  show    unlock  unmute  
pro-sip*CLI> confbridge mute <TAB pressed, only one conference, so it will be auto-fill>
pro-sip*CLI> confbridge mute 1234  <TAB pressed here>
all                               Local/100@conferences-00000013;2  participants  

pro-sip*CLI> confbridge mute 1234 all
Muting all from confbridge 1234
pro-sip*CLI>

pro-sip*CLI> confbridge list 1234 
Channel                        Flags  User Profile     Bridge Profile   Menu             CallerID
============================== ====== ================ ================ ================ ================
Local/100@conferences-00000013;2 m      default_user     default_bridge   default_menu     <unknown>
```

So, **m**  here mean muted

Lets ensure:

```
pro-sip*CLI> confbridge unmute 1234 all
Unmuting all from confbridge 1234
pro-sip*CLI> confbridge list 1234
Channel                        Flags  User Profile     Bridge Profile   Menu             CallerID
============================== ====== ================ ================ ================ ================
Local/100@conferences-00000013;2        default_user     default_bridge   default_menu     <unknown>
```

ps almost any command in asterisk allow press TAB to show hints/variants.

Comment: you are right, I was using asterisk version 11, confbridge mute/unmute  all was not working in it. Just tested it on asterisk 16, confbridge mute/unmute all is working. Thanks.

Comment: I am pretty sure it has worked since 1.8.x. DO NOT use versions not marked as LTS for development. At this moment, you should use 18 or 20. https://www.asterisk.org/downloads/asterisk/all-asterisk-versions/